# Cannot see existing files on Android phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Consider the following code:

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string file = Path.Combine(folder, "test.txt");
File.WriteAllText(file, "test");
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Running this on my phone I confirmed that the string `content` has the value "test", so the file has definitely been created and written to in internal storage.

Next I commented the `WriteAllText`-line and verified on a second run of the program that the file was still there because the value of `content` again was "test".

But when I look into the folder returned by `GetFolderPath` using the file manager of my phone, it is empty. There is no file `test.txt`.

So the question is, why can't I see the file?

Comment: Because unless your phone is rooted and the file manager running as root, it doesn't have the correct permissions.  The data directory for an application is application private.  Your file manager doesn't have permission to even see files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the phone is rooted and the file manager as root permissions you cannot see those files (usually under /data/data/package.name/files)

If you want to see them using your code, consider using this:

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Your app should log them with no problem.

If the files are needed outside the app, consider using external storage.